# import node module from lambda layer locally in AWS SAM

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, es6-modules, aws-sam, aws-lambda-layers

I'm trying to import (ES6) node_module from lambda layer locally in sam project
my node handler:

```
import { uid } from 'uid';

export async function handler(event, context) {
    const demo = uid(16);
    console.log("testing ", demo);

    const response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "*/*"
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify({ uid: uid(16) }),
        "isBase64Encoded": false
    };
    return response;
}
```

my file structure:
[image]

I tried to change the files structure